# PHPunit tests fail when running as a group

Tags: php, phpunit

When running a full test suite in PHPUnit that is defined in my phpunit.xml all of my unit tests run and pass.

If I then run a particular group of tests I get a Fatal error as classes I am trying to mock can't be found.

I have a Bootstrap.php file that set's up an autoloader and from what I can see the Bootstrap is used in both cases.

Anyone experienced this before, or have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe show your test that is failing, bootstrap.php and the command line you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have had that error happen on occasion.  Without know more about your autoloader or your setup, you can fix the problem with your mocks by using `disableAutoload` on the classes.

Using the MockBuilder interface:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')->disableAutoload()->getMock();
```

Or

```
$mock = $this->getMock('SomeClass', array(), null, null, true, true, true)
                                                disables Autoload ----^
```

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest.php

- By default, all methods of the given class are replaced with a test
  double that just returns NULL unless a return value is configured
  using will($this->returnValue()), for instance.
- When the second (optional) parameter is provided, only the methods
  whose names are in the array are replaced with a configurable test
  double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed. Providing
  NULL as the parameter means that no methods will be replaced.
- The third (optional) parameter may hold a parameter array that is
  passed to the original class' constructor (which is not replaced with
  a dummy implementation by default).
- The fourth (optional) parameter can be used to specify a class name
  for the generated test double class.
- The fifth (optional) parameter can be used to disable the call to the
  original class' constructor.
- The sixth (optional) parameter can be used to disable the call to the
  original class' clone constructor.
- The seventh (optional) parameter can be used to disable __autoload()
  during the generation of the test double class.